# how to scrape all the pages of this link

Tags: python, scrapy

i want to **scrape** all the pages of this link, http://www.jobisjob.co.uk/search?directUserSearch=true&whatInSearchBox=&whereInSearchBox=london.

I have tried different ways but i didn't get any solution.

below is my code

```
import scrapy

    class jobisjobSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    
        enter code here
        name = 'jobisjob'
        allowed_domains = ['jobisjob.co.uk']
    
        start_urls = ['http://www.jobisjob.co.uk/search?directUserSearch=true&whatInSearchBox=&whereInSearchBox=london']
    
    
        def parse(self, response):
            
            for sel in response.xpath('//div[@id="ajax-results"]/div[@class="offer_list "]/div[@class="box_offer"]/div[@class="offer"]'):
                
                item = JobgoItem()
                item['title'] = sel.xpath('strong[@class="title"]/a/text()').extract()
                item['description'] = sel.xpath('p[@class="description"]/text()').extract()
                item['company'] = sel.xpath('p[@class="company"]/span[@itemprop="hiringOrganization"]/a[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract()
                item['location'] = sel.xpath('p[@class="company"]/span/span[@class="location"]/span/text()').extract()
    
                
                yield item
    
            next_page = response.css("div.wrap paginator results > ul > li > a[rel='nofollow']::attr('href')")
            if next_page:
    
                url = response.urljoin(next_page[0].extract())
                print "next page: " + str(url)
    
                yield scrapy.Request(url)
```

Could any one help for solving this problem, i am totally new in python

Answer (score 0):

You have error in next page selector. 
Your current selector searching tags with name `wrap` and then `paginator` inside `div` with class `wrap`.

Right selector is

`div.wrap.paginator.results > ul > li > a:last-child[rel='nofollow']::attr('href')`